# Get context from admin-site on a sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

How can i authenticate my administration site, and get that context from a sitecollection?

My current code is below

```
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com");
 ctx.username = ""
 ctx.password = ""
```